# Radio buttons using Simple Form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am struggling to understand the Simple Form documentation. I have a form in my Rails 4 app - which has been built with simple_form.

I have read the Simple Form documentation. I just can't understand it and can't find any resource to help with breaking it down.

The documentation provides the following example for using radio buttons in simple form:

```
 f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last
```

and you can see from the documentation that it goes on to describe labels to apply.

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder#collection_radio_buttons-instance_method

I can't understand this documentation in several respects. What does :first, :last do?  I get an error (undefined method `merge' for :last:Symbol) when I try to follow this example. I don't understand any of the construct of the label examples in the documentation. Is there a  break down of these example anywhere that you could refer me to?

I have tried to gather feedback from answers to other's posts and have come up with the following. Please can someone help me identify what is wrong with this line.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :project_image, :options, [[true, 'Yes'], [false, 'No']], :first, :last, :default => true, label: 'Would you like add an image to your project pitch?'  %>
```

I'm keen to learn how to use Simple Form but feel that the documentation is beyond my grasp on its own. I have used the Railscasts to fill some of the gaps but suggestions for other resources to help me improve would be gratefully received.

Thank you.

Comment: explain what you are trying to achieve in the form

Comment: I would like a label that says: "Would you like to add a project image?". I have a boolean attribute in my model for project image that is either true or false. I'd like radio buttons to use in making that selection. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document is easy to understand.

```
- (Object) collection_radio_buttons(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

`collection_radio_buttons` have those params .

```
f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last
```

For this expamle

- `:options` is method name.
- `[[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']]` is the collection, it's an array of array, all the member has the stucture of [value, lable].
- `:first` is the radio button's value_method, means to get how to get value from every member of the collection, use first method can get `true` and `false` from the members in the collection.
- `:last` is the radio button's text_method, to generate lable for every radio button.

So you may just use replace the method name to `project_image` and add another lable like this:

```
<%=f.collection_radio_buttons :project_image, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last %>
<%=f.lable  :project_image, 'Would you like add an image to your project pitch?'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

this might make more sense

```
 <%= f.input :project_image, :as => :boolean, input_html: {checked: false} %>
```

Comment: Hi Franklin, thanks for the suggestion, but how does that create the radio button option?

Comment: :as => :boolean creates a radio button

Comment: yes, but it only creates one button (as in tick if you'd like to add an image. I can do that as a back up plan but would like to learn.